# How to get height of UILabel, UITextView in Swift after dynamic resize

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a UILabel and a UITextView created in storyboard that both change height to  fit the text that is passed into them. I need to fetch the height of both of them programmatically in order to size my view correctly (view embedded in scroll view), but when I run this code in their view controller, it gives me the height defined in storyboard rather than the resized height. articleText is my text view, and articleLabel my label.

```
articleText.attributedText = largeTextString
articleLabel.attributedText = labelString

print(articleText.contentSize.height) 
print(articleLabel.bounds.size.height)
// Both return storyboard value, not resized value
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific in which part of the viewController class did you run this code? (eg. viewDidLoad)

Comment: My viewDidLoad calls a function to setup the view, which contains this code.

Comment: Then you need to delay running this code until your view is fully setup, maybe tie it to a IBAction or start a NSTimer for a selector instead of the viewDidLoad

Comment: That makes sense. I ran the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews and it works now. Thanks!